# Sitecore workbox - Modify "Message box" popup box from single line textbox to a multiline textbox

Tags: sitecore

Sitecore workbox displays workflow actions available from the current state. For actions if "Supress message" is turned off, it displays a message box to enter a reason for the action.

Is it possible to customize this? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a multiline textbox instead of a single-line textbox, just add the `TextMode="MultiLine"` attribute to the WorkflowComment.ascx file in the location Trayek describes in his answer.

You might also need to modify the CSS to make it fit better.

If this is the only change you need, you don't have to change the class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the file `<websiteroot>/sitecore/shell/feeds/Views/WorkflowComment.ascx` that is the control used. 
So while it looks like it *can* be modified, but I haven't done this before, so I'm not entirely sure what happens when it's changed to a different type though. For instance, the file `<websiteroot>/sitecore/shell/feeds/workflow.js` seems to use the field as well.

If you do try to change it, you'll have to change the `Sitecore.Shell.Feeds.Views.WorkflowComment` class as well, since it's expecting a Textbox.